# How to fix naming and scoping conflict?

Tags: delphi, scope, naming, conflict

Error: Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical

```
unit unAutoKeypress;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
procedure SimulateKeyDown(Key:byte);
begin
keybd_event(Key,0,0,0);
end;

procedure SimulateKeyUp(Key:byte);
begin
keybd_event(Key,0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
end;

procedure doKeyPress(var KeyValue:byte);
begin
 SimulateKeyDown(KeyValue);
 SimulateKeyUp(KeyValue);
end;



procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const test = 'merry Christmas!';
var m: byte;
begin
Memo2.SetFocus();
m:=$13;
doKeyPress(m); // THIS IS WHERE ERROR
end;

end.
```

always error in function doKeyPress(m); 
 a simple question, why?

I know something wrong with types, but all types are similar, everywhere is byte, strange
 for me and I cant run a program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `doKeyPress` is a method of `TForm1` (inherited from `TWinControl`) and so when you write `doKeyPress` inside a `TForm1` method the compiler wants to use `TForm1.doKeyPress` rather than the local function. The class scope is nearer than the local function scope.

Possible solutions include:

- Renaming the local function to avoid the clash.
- Using a fully qualified name, `unAutoKeypress.doKeyPress`.

The former is a better solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

`TForm` is inherited from `TWinControl` and there is a method called `DoKeyPress` declared in `TWinControl`, which is in the current scope of the compiler inside the `ButtonClick` event.

Comment: What I can to do for the events was valid, how to separate them?